# Querying result from mongoose using dynamic model.find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to find the results of a query with mongoose `find({})` method in Node.js with a variable containing model name.

```
var adSchema     =  new Schema({ schema defination });
var Ad           =  mongoose.model('Ad', adSchema);
var variableName = 'Ad';
variableName.find({}).exec(function (err, adObj) {});
```

Is it possible or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do that when calling `model` with just the name like so

```
mongoose.model('Ad').find({}).exec(function (err, adObj) {});
```

See [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model) for the corresponding part of the official docs

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var anySchema = new Schema({
      fieldname:  String
    });
    var Test = mongoose.model('Test', anySchema);
    Test.find({}).exec(function(err,result){});
```